# Transforming a single xml to many documents

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have to create a mapping between two xsd schemas, where the input document contains a list (sequence) of elements, each of which maps to a single output document. Moreover, each output document should include top level input data that is not a part of the list. To illustrate the problem, the input document contains data about a customer (contact info, etc) and list of invoices for them, and the output should be multiple documents, each containing one invoice and the customer data.

Can I somehow do this using DataMapper or some other approach? If I create a mapping between the input list elements and the output document, DataMapper will output an aggregation of all the created output documents. It also seems that I can not refer to the input top level elements from inside the "list element to output document" mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing root element in your source XSD contained a list of "Item" elements, you could first split the document into Items:

```
<splitter expression="#[xpath('//Item')]" doc:name="Splitter" enableCorrelation="IF_NOT_SET"/>
```

And then after the splitter use a DataMapper to map the Item elements to a target element in your other XSD.  DataMapper requires that "Item" also be a root element in your source XSD in order to do the mapping from XSD to XSD.  If it's not possible/desirable to make "Item" a  root element in the source XSD, then you could create a sample XML and use DataMapper to generate an XSD from that.  Otherwise you could roll your own transformer or use the XSLT transformer.

Comment: Modifying the XSD:s is not an option, as they are national / international standards. They are also pretty big and complex documents, so I'd like to use the original xsd:s and DataMapper as far as possible to avoid errors. The best approach I could think so far, is parsing the customer info separately, and splitting the aggregated output String generated by DataMapper using the root element name.